# Firestore Generic Repository

Tags: android, database, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, repository-pattern

I want to make a generic repository that does operations on a firestore collection that uses maps instead of any POJOs. I have implemented a function that retrieves only the required fields from the document, it converts it to the desired type and return the new map inside a wrapper class `RequestState`.

```
sealed class RequestState(val result:Any?) {
    class Error(exception: Exception):RequestState(exception)
    class Loading():RequestState(null)
    class Success(data:Any):RequestState(data)
}

override suspend fun retrieveFields(
        documentName: String,
        fields: List<String>,
        expectedType: List<KClass<*>>
    ): Flow<RequestState> = callbackFlow {
        try {
            // Check if the fields or expectedType lists are empty
            if (fields.isEmpty() || expectedType.isEmpty()) throw EmptyArgument(requestName = "Retrieve Fields")

            // Check if the fields and expectedType lists have the same size
            if (fields.size != expectedType.size) throw InvalidSize(
                requestName = "Retrieve Fields",
                cause = "The args don't have the same amount of items"
            )

            trySend(RequestState.Loading())

            // Retrieve the document with the given name
            this@CollectionRepositoryImpl.collection.document(documentName).get()
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    // Handle the failure case and close the flow
                    trySend(RequestState.Error(exception))
                    close()
                }.addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                // Create a mutable map to store the retrieved fields
                val resultMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
                document.data?.let { map ->
                    // Iterate over the fields and expected types
                    fields.onEachIndexed { index, fieldName ->
                        if (fieldName in map.keys) {
                            // Store the field and its expected type in the resultMap
                            val data = document to expectedType[index]
                            resultMap[fieldName] = data
                        } else {
                            Log.w(
                                "Test",
                                "The field $fieldName was not found inside the document $documentName"
                            )
                            throw NoSuchField(fieldName, "Retrieve Fields")
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Send the success action with the resultMap and close the flow
                trySend(RequestState.Success(resultMap))
                close()
            }

            awaitClose()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle any exceptions and close the flow
            trySend(RequestState.Error(e))
            close()
        }
    }
```

I'm stuck when i have to use the result outside of the function , because i have it to type cast it back to `Map<String, Any>` and loose all the information about the type

Comment: What do you mean by "use the result outside of the function"?

Comment: I have to use the emitted `RequestState` in the viewModel and i must cast it from `Any` to the map `<String , Any?>`  i need , and i get an exception when i do the conversion.  As a work around i decided to use templates instead , much easier :)))